# Is there a reusable UITableViewCell with a label and text field?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, ios4

It's a common user interface pattern throughout iOS to have a grouped UITableView where each cell displays a label alongside a text field. It is used to collect textual information from the user, e.g a username and password when logging in to a service.

Does the iOS framework provide this boilerplate UITableViewCell, or will I have to create a custom cell myself? I've scoured the docs and open source libraries without any luck, and I'd rather not have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: UIKit Framework has no cells of this type. But it's quite simple to create your own .XIB file with custom `UITableViewCell` in it. Make references to `UITextField` and `UILabel`, after that just load and return it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at ELCTextFieldCell?:

http://icodeblog.com/2011/01/04/elctextfieldcell-a-useful-tableviewcell-for-forms/
https://github.com/elc/ELCTextFieldCell

Comment: This looks like a nice solution; thank you. I also found a similar cell in the Tapku library: https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

Comment: Thanks, Tapku looks interesting.

Comment: Does pressing the cell row also activate the text field?